# How do i fetch the data from Core Data to use it for flashcards?

Tags: swift, database, swiftui, core-data

The problem is to fetch the data from `CoreData` and implement it in flashcards.

I have created a new view `FlashCardSetsView` where I tried to use the view of flashcards I have already created, however, my program doesn't want to fetch the data.
Here is what I have:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct FlashCardSetsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    @State private var flashcardSets: [FlashCardData] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(flashcardSets) { set in
                NavigationLink(destination: FlashCardsListView(flashcardSet: set)) {
                    Text(set.name ?? "")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Flashcard Sets")
        }
        .onAppear {
            dataController.fetchRequest()
            flashcardSets = dataController.savedFlash
        }
    }
}

struct FlashCardsListView: View {
    let flashcardSet: FlashCardData
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: FlashCardData.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var flashcards: FetchedResults<FlashCardData>
        
    
    var body: some View {
        List(flashcards) { flashcard in
         //   FlashCardView(card: flashcard)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(flashcardSet.name ?? "")
        .onAppear {
            let context = dataController.container.viewContext
            let request = NSFetchRequest<FlashCardData>(entityName: "FlashCardData")
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "tag == %@", flashcardSet.tag ?? "")
            request.predicate = predicate
            do {
                flashcards = try context.viewContext.fetch(request) // error: 1) Cannot assign to property: 'flashcards' is a get-only property
                 //   2) Value of type 'NSManagedObjectContext' has no member 'viewContext'
            } catch let error {
                print("Error fetching flashcards: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}



struct FlashCardSetsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FlashCardSetsView()
    }
}
```

I can also provide the `DataController` but it's a basic one with "fetch" and "add" functions.

Comment: It often helps when dealing with CoreData to upload a copy of the Entity that you are using. However, you may not have enough reputation for that. Firstly, I think you have the data flow backward. Your `FlashCardSetsView` is the parent view, and the `FlashCardsListView` is your detail view where you deal with one `FlashCardData`. So, my first piece of advice is remove the `@State private var flashcardSets: [FlashCardData] = []` and simply put in its place the `@FetchRequest(entity: FlashCardData.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var flashcards: FetchedResults<FlashCardData>`. Remove the onAppear.

Comment: You can’t mix @FetchRequest and NSFetchRequest, use one or the other.